# cannot re-use pandas generator object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the scenario as below (running tests for performance bench marking):

```
def read_sql_query(query, chunk_size, cnxn):
    try:
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn, index_col=['product_key'], chunksize=100000)
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def return_chunks_in_df(df, start_date, end_date):
    try:

        sub_df = pd.DataFrame()
        for chunks in df:            
            sub_df = pd.concat([sub_df, chunks.loc[(chunks['trans_date'] > start_date) & (chunks['trans_date'] < end_date)]], ignore_index=True)
        print(sub_df.info())
        return sub_df    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

query = r"select * from  sales_rollup where  product_key in (select product_key from temp limit 10000)"

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
df = read_sql_query(query, 100000, cnxn)
print(df)
print('time to chunk:' + str(timeit.default_timer() - start_time))

#scenario 1
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
sub_df1 = return_chunks_in_df(df, '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01')
print('scenario1:' + str(timeit.default_timer() - start_time))

#scenario 2    
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
sub_df2 = return_chunks_in_df(df, '2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
print('scenario2:' + str(timeit.default_timer() - start_time))
```

The issue I am having is in scenario 2 where the dataframe always returns 0 rows even though there is data for the filtered date range. I tried looping through the df() but the below loop never runs:

```
for chunks in df:
    print(chunks.info())
```

I am only able to get the result set for scenario 2 if I recreate the df again as below just before execution:

```
df = read_sql_query(query, 100000, cnxn)
```

The core issue being the first to execute scenario always returns values the second does not. Does the df object expire somehow after first execution?
Any help/pointers highly appreciated.

Comment: what's with down voting without stating a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators are "used up" after the first run through:

```
def gen(n):
   for i in range(n):
       yield i

In [11]: g = gen(3)

In [12]: list(g)
Out[12]: [0, 1, 2]

In [13]: list(g)
Out[13]: []
```

In order to reuse them you could refactor to allow you to pass the chunk to both:

```
def concat_chunk(acc, chunk, start_date, end_date):
    return pd.concat([acc, chunk.loc[(chunk['trans_date'] > start_date) & (chunk['trans_date'] < end_date)]], ignore_index=True)

sub_df1 = pd.DataFrame()
sub_df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in df:
    sub_df1 = concat_chunk(sub_df1, chunk, '2015-01-01', '2016-01-01')
    sub_df2 = concat_chunk(sub_df2, chunk, '2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')
```

*Note: distributing it this way will throw off your timings...*

---

You may also prefer to move the `where` logic into SQL:

```
query = r"""select * from sales_rollup
            where product_key in (select product_key from temp limit 10000) 
            and '2015-01-01' < trans_date
            and trans_date < '2016-01-01'"""
```

That way, perhaps you'll have no need of chunks!

---

In general, the way to "reuse a generator" is just make it a list... but that usually defeats the point (of building it piecemeal):

```
chunks = list(df)  # Note chunks is probably a more descriptive name...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sub_df = pd.DataFrame()
for chunks in df:            
    sub_df = pd.concat([sub_df, ...
print(sub_df.info())
return sub_df
```

don't know why u set sub_df twice, it'll make the first setting invalid.

to figure this kind of issue, u need thinking reversely.
first u should only run one command:

```
sub_df = pd.concat([sub_df, ...
```

feed the parameters by static items, not variables.

if this is no problem, then u need to find why ur original program can not provide the correct param for  pd.concat

Comment: if it's helpful pls let me know ^_^

Comment: Hi Zhen, thanks for the quick response. I did not understand your comment on setting sub_df twice. The first instance is declaring the dataframe as without that I will not be able to concat,